# Queria saber se cada vez que crio um objeto em java ele inicializa uma Thread

Tags: java

Tenho uma classe que estende a classe Thread, queria saber se cada vez que crio um objeto ele inicializa uma Thread.

```
class Objeto{

      String nomeObjeto;

      public Objeto(String nomeObjeto){
          this.nomeObjeto = nomeObjeto;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args){
          new Objeto().start();//Objeto 1
          new Objeto().start();//Objeto 2
      }

}
```

Comment: Ahh, eu esqueci uma coisa no código, esta classe estende a classe Thread

Comment: Criar apenas o objecto não inicia a *Thread* terá de chamar o método `Start()` como no código que postou: `new Objeto().start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais básica de se criar um *thread* (linha de execução) em Java é criando uma nova instância da classe 'Thread' e chamando o método 'start()', após o qual o método 'run()' da instância será executado na outra *thread*.

O método 'run()' da classe 'Thread' não executa nada, por isso em geral estendemos a classe e sobrescrevemos o método. Outra alternativa é criar uma classe que implementa a interface 'Runnable' e passar uma instância dessa classe no construtor da classe 'Thread'.

Enfim, ao criar uma instância de 'Thread' ou uma subclasse você potencialmente terá uma nova *thread*, mas que somente executará quando der o 'start()' nela.

Cada nova instância que você executa é uma nova *thread* e somente uma, já que threads não podem ser reaproveitadas, isto é, executadas mais de uma vez.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código provavelmente não está completo pois sua classe `Objeto` não tem um método `start()`.

Se o que está faltando é o `extends Thread`, então, sim, ao colocar isso, serão criadas duas threads (uma em cada chamada de `start()`). Isso pode ser verificado na [documentação oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29).

Se o que está faltando é a definição de `start()`, sendo esse um método qualquer criado por você, então, não, não serão criadas threads.